# how can I create a cancel button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.9

Hi I'm new in tkinter and I was trying to code a window with a button creating a new window. I want to add a new button (for cancel) in new window. I cant add a cancel button in my second window.

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

master = Tk()

master.geometry("200x200")

def openNewWindow():

    newWindow = Toplevel(master)

    newWindow.title("New Window")

    newWindow.geometry("200x200")

    Label(newWindow,
          text="This is a new window").pack()

label = Label(master,
              text="This is the main window")

label.pack(pady=10)

btn = Button(master,
             text="Click to open a new window",
             command=openNewWindow)
btn.pack(pady=10)

mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I cant add a cancel button in my second window."_ - Why can't you add the button to the new window? Your code doesn't show any attempt at doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following code lines at the end of `openNewWindow` function to `destroy` newWindow.

```
clo = Button(
    newWindow, text = "Close new window", command = newWindow.destroy)
clo.pack(pady = 10)
```

If you need to perform some action before destroying `newWindow` then create a function.

```
def closer():
    # do something
    newWindow.destroy()
```

And change `openNewWindow` close button like this.

```
clo = Button(
    newWindow, text = "Close new window", command = closer)
clo.pack(pady = 10)
```